# How to get the previous state of the repository in git?

Tags: git, github

I need to get back to the specific state in the repository.

I try this:

```
git push -f origin <sha_of_previous_commit>:master
```

but I think it does even more mess...

This is my current state:

```
*comit4 <-branch_name[1 note]
|
*comit3 <-[1 note]
|
*comit2 <- master
|
*comit1
|
*Added basic information.
|
*Initial commit
```

And I would like it to be like this:

```
*Added basic information. <-master
|
*Initial commit
```

The last SHA of commit that I see in the log is from `commit2`.

Actually `commit3` and `commit4` should be in another branch but when I pushed it stay in the master branch. Then I try the command above and this happened.

Please can you help me how to get back the state above?

Comment: `git reflog` is your friend.

Answer (score 0):

The following command should help you:

```
git reset HEAD@{1}
```

I also highly recommend using `git reflog`. This command manages the information recorded in the reflogs.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is trivial because **every commit holds a full snapshot of every file.**  So:

> ```
> *comit4 <-branch_name[1 note]
> |
> *comit3 <-[1 note]
> |
> *comit2 <- master
> |
> *comit1
> |
> *Added basic information.
> |
> *Initial commit
> ```

(I'm using your misspelling of `commit` here where appropriate, to match your question.)

Branch *names*, like `master`, simply serve to help you (and Git) *find* one *specific* commit, namely the *last* commit of the branch.  So:

> ... I would like it to be like this:
>
> ```
> *Added basic information. <-master
> |
> *Initial commit
> ```

This merely requires that you tell Git to make the *name* `master` find that commit.

To do that, you use `git branch` or `git reset`, with whatever options are required.  For `git branch`:

- you must not be *on* the branch at the time (so you must be "on" some other branch), and
- you need to use the `--force` option.

If you don't have another branch to be "on", you can use `git reset`, which is a bit more complicated (you need to choose from `--soft`, `--mixed`, or `--hard`).  But you go on to say:

> Actually `commit3` and `commit4` should be in another branch but when I pushed it stay in the master branch.

Commits are often on *multiple branches at the same time*, not just *one* branch.  The set of commits that are "on" a branch are those you can reach by following the graph line backwards ("down the page", given the way you have drawn the commits here).  So you would just set some *other* branch name to point to the last commit.  That way those commits are on that branch—and, until you adjust `master`, on *both* branches.

> I [ran]
>
> ```
> git push -f origin <sha_of_previous_commit>:master
> ```

The `git push` command:

1. sends any needed commits to some *other* Git repository, then
2. asks or commands the *other* Git repository to set some of *its* branch name(s)

so, assuming you used the hash ID for `comit2` here, this sent `comit2` to the other Git repository if it did not already have it, sent `comit1` if they did not have *that*, sent `Added basic information` if they did not have *that*, and sent `Initial commit` if they did not have *that*.  At this point they had all the needed commits, so it commanded (`-f`) them to set *their* name `master`.

If you were not denied permission—basic Git can't do that as it has no permissions controls at all, but most hosting sites add on permissions for obvious reasons—this got what you wanted in *some other Git repository*.  It did not do anything for *your* Git repository.

To fix up *your* Git repository, you should first create the name you want:

```
git branch new-branch-name
```

and then switch to it:

```
git switch new-branch-name
```

(you can combine these into `git switch -c new-branch-name` if you prefer, or the old `git checkout -b new-branch-name` if your Git is too old to have `git switch`).  That makes it easy to use `git branch -f` to move your `master` back:

```
git branch -f master <hash ID for second commit>
```

which forcibly moves your `master` backwards to point to `comit2`.

Since this doesn't need `git reset`, we don't have to get complicated with the soft/mixed/hard stuff.  That's the way to go here.